# Advice on data dashboard setup

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, cloud

Here's what I am trying to achieve:

1. I would like my community (customers) to have access to data and for that data to be visualized in a dashboard. The data would be a mix of API based info plus my own JSON/ .csv data.
2. I would also like this data (and dashboard) to be password protected to my community and accessed via my own domain?

Should my approach be something like Google Cloud Platform or Amazon Elastic Stack?

Any ideas/ thoughts and suggestions would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has [Data Studio](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-data-studio) where you can visualize [BigQuery Data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/) using SQL queries. Sample call:

```
SELECT
 source_year,
 sum(case when is_male then 1 else 0 end) as male_births,
 sum(case when is_male then 0 else 1 end) as female_births
FROM
 `bigquery-public-data.samples.natality`
GROUP BY
 source_year
ORDER BY
 source_year
DESC
```

Here is the [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-data-studio) for the official documentation.